# can i access itunes com interface through windows services?

Tags: c++, service, com, itunes, itunesartwork

can i access itunes com interface through c++ based windows services? It is failing at cocreateinstance() function when called from a windows service . As a normal application, same code is working fine. This service is created by converting the this working application. It is working fine for other COMs.

Comment: Probably itunes wants to interact with the desktop, but cannot from session 0

Comment: what is the error code?

Comment: Is iTunes running as a service, or are you trying to access a running iTunes from a (separate) windows service application?

Comment: Actually i have created an interactive service and I'm impersonating the current user also before calling CoCreateInstance. This way I'm able to use other COM but not able to use iTunes COM. It is going giving me logs put before CoCreateInstance() but no log after calling CoCreateInstance().

Comment: no you won't, session 0 isolation will prevent you from starting a UI, there are ways to bypass it but i'm sure it won't work well with itunes. Search for session 0 interactive services.

Answer (score 0):

Actually iTunes com always launches iTunes before communicating with it. I tried to verify with other COM interfaces also (like IE and WMP). All were able to interact using windows service but iTunes was not communicating with Windows Service. So **my answer is NO**. You should not use windows service if you are planning to communicate with iTunes using COM.